# Frequent BSOD on laptop

Tags: bsod, lenovo-laptop

I recently bought a laptop Lenovo G700, for a while it worked fine, but about a month ago it started having problems. Laptop has become BSOD issue with the code CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT. I reinstalled and the problem for some time ceased. Two weeks it all started again, the laptop gives BSOD with different error codes. Even when I trying to reinstall OS. I tried to put Ubuntu, the system established normally, but after 15 minutes of use, the system has issued a black screen. I checked the RAM using memtest86, it showed no errors. Can you please suggest what could it be?

Comment: upload the dmp files in 1 zip file (Skydrive, dropbox and post a link)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I understand in Linux no dmp files, so here is a link to sislog [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ip06n367fulj04/syslog.zip), or you need something else?

Comment: I have no idea about the Linux log file, so it is useless for me. I need a Windows dmp file.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT error code means that your processor is having trouble with cooperation from its cores and threads.

This is most probably caused by your processor (CPU).

Here are some things to should try:

1. Run your Laptop in SAFE MODE and update all drivers
2. Update your BIOS
3. If you've done any over clocking, undo this.

If the above doesn't resolve your issue, I'd suggest contacting your manufactures.

> This information and more is found here:
>
> http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2013/01/clock-watchdog-timeout/

Comment: BIOS can not be updated. As I understand it on ubuntu separately placed only on the video card drivers, but they and the system itself is fully updated. At this point the system hangs after 5 seconds of loading and nothing else happens, then now there is no black screen. Just an unresponsive system.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a major hardware issue, it's hard to say what specifically, you might need to take it to a computer repair shop. Check your BIOS settings, undo any overclocking, Google any error codes from the BSODs since they might help narrow down what the specific issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Overheating can cause some WEIRD responses.  Make sure it's nice and cool.  Turn off the power and clean out the vents with some compressed air.  When you use it, make sure nothing is obstructing those vents.

Comment: For example during memtest86 temperature did not rise above 47 degrees, so I don't think it's overheating

Comment: Memtest doesn't put a load on the processor!  On my laptop it gets hottest if I'm playing 3d games or watching Netflix. :P

Comment: This makes sense :) But still, the laptop only 3 months and when I examined it, there was not really a lot of dust

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD processor and getting the `CLOCK WATCH DOG TIMEOUT` it seems it related to the emergency windows updates (regarding Spectre and Meltdown) that Microsoft put out that ended up causing issues for AMD PCs.

It was presumed that it only affected older AMD CPUs such as the Athlon series, but upon further research, it turns out that certain Ryzen and Threadripper CPUs were affected.

After uninstalling KB4056895 (Monthly Rollup Update), the CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT BSODs and PC lock ups stopped. I can say this after having my PC run for almost 24 hrs.

look for these installed updates and try removing them.

- January 3, 2018—KB4056897 (Security-only update)
- January 9, 2018—KB4056894 (Monthly Rollup)
- January 3, 2018—KB4056888 (OS Build 10586.1356)
- January 3, 2018—KB4056892 (OS Build 16299.192)
- January 3, 2018—KB4056891 (OS Build 15063.850)
- January 3, 2018—KB4056890 (OS Build 14393.2007)
- January 3, 2018—KB4056898 (Security-only update)
- January 3, 2018—KB4056893 (OS Build 10240.17735)
  January 9, 2018—KB4056895 (Monthly Rollup)

Taken from - https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/667764/clock-watchdog-timeout-bsod-problems/ - GHNeko answer