# BSOD Clock watchdog timeout Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, timeout, watch

**ISSUE OS:**
Windows 10 Enterprise.

**HARDWARE:**
MSI X370 SLI PLUS, Ryzen 1600, 32GB DDR4 2133, 250G SSD, 850W TT Gold PSU and Gigabyte RX580 8GB

**ISSUE DESCRIPTION:** Fresh install, OS works, installed drivers and apps (not Nortons tho) from the MSI dvd. Windows worked.....updates....games started to be installed....tried Northgard annnnnd crash.
And it went from there.
BSOD (the times i actually got one):
  ***ERROR:***

***BSOD Clock watchdog timeout***

**EFFORTS:**
removed apps. then removed drivers. then readded fresh new latest drivers for one thing* at a time.
Same issue, Clock watchdog timeout BSOD after 1minute to maybe 5 mins uptime.

I even tried a different VGA card.
Hopefully this will help others as I go thru this I will update on progress and a fix.

Comment: checkout this forum - https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/clock-watchdog-timeout-windows-10.2966893/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found my fix:
1. Downloaded a current (April 2018) ISO of Windows 10 64-bit from Microsoft

2. Downgraded product from "Enterprise" to "Pro"
3. HIGHLY LIKELY issue with UPDATES for Spectre and Meltdown

Windows now works!! those new updates are not installed yet (unless they are part of the new ISO i used.)

Helpful people were:
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/667764/clock-watchdog-timeout-bsod-problems/
http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3352007/clock-watchdog-timeout-windows.html
:-)

Comment: is anyone who downvoted able to explain why you felt you needed to do that? are you prepared to help me learn to be a better member and follow in your your example of being better please? I dont know what i did wrong by providing this answer that worked?

Comment: I found your answer useful, in fact used the answer from the forums to answer another similar one- https://superuser.com/questions/704509/frequent-bsod-on-laptop/1645996#1645996 - I will try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with my ASUS Vivobook X505Z

The following steps took me many hours but it seems I have found the problem

- I got a new Windows ISO
- I used AVG Driver Updater to update all drivers (did not updated my video)
- I reflashed the bios with the current version (you can try previous version)
- As soon as I installed the Radeon Vega 8 driver the Clock watchdog timeout returned

Is seems that the driver conflicts with Windows build 1511
https://community.amd.com/t5/graphics/ryzen-3-2200g-vega-8-driver-problem/td-p/53336

So I disabled the RADEON and rolled back to the `Microsoft Basic Display driver`